# Choosing charts controls library

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, flash, charts

I am looking for easy customizable charts. 
For example, i need to do this chart
[image]

And this:
[image]

And many other.

So...What is best technplogy, flash, silverlight(on server side asp.net WebForms), js. Is it good idea to write own chart conrols without based on exists controls?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything that meets your needs exactly, there are a ton of charting controls out there. But, I reckon you should go with a javascript library because of iOS limitations on Flash and Silverlight.

Write your own? No way, unless that's your core business. Perhaps modify an open source one or suggest to a vendor that you'll buy theirs if they implement a critical feature for you (or help you with it).

I've used [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and there are [plenty of other JS ones out there](http://www.splashnology.com/article/15-awesome-free-javascript-charts/325/). I would also look at [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/) as I've heard good things about them and they have WPF, Silverlight and JS options.

HighCharts and amCharts are not free. amCharts seems localisable too.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't build it unless it is your core business. I also believe that Silverlight gives your user a rich-experience that is unmatched in other technologies.

You could easily product that chart using Telerik Controls. Matter of fact, they have a wide variety of charts including this [one](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/DrillDown) that you can play around with. You may want to start with this [page](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/FirstLook) and click the "Other Chart Examples" drop down to see what they have to offer.